# Как задать фокус полю клинированной формы?

Tags: jquery

Клонирую форму. Как у клонированной формы полю задать фокус?

**HTML** изначальной формы:

```
<form class="comment_form js-comment_form clearfix" action="#">
    <div class="avatar_block">
        <img class="avatar" src="img/avatar.jpg" alt="avatar">
    </div>
    <div class="field_column">
        <div class="field_block">
            <textarea class="field js-comment_field" name="comment" placeholder="Оставьте комментарий"></textarea>
            <div class="line"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="buttons_block js-comment-buttons">
            <div class="button cansel_button js-cansel_button">Отмена</div>
            <button class="button js-comment_button" disabled>Оставить комментарий</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(".js-reply_button").click(function(){
        var i = 1;
        var buttons = $(this).parents(".js-buttons_block");
        $(".js-comment_form").clone().insertAfter(buttons).attr("id", "js-comment_form_"+i++);
        $(".js-comment_form_"+i).find(".js-comment_field").focus();
    });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы назначаете один `id`, а выбираете по другому `class`-у.

```
    var newId = "js-comment_form_" + i++;
    $(".js-comment_form").clone().insertAfter(buttons).attr("id", newId);
    $("#" + newId).find(".js-comment_field").focus();
```

Comment: Форма клонируется с нужным ID, все хорошо. Но теперь клонированная форма не отправляется и кнопки не нажимаются.

Comment: @Frontender Мои изменения не могли на это повлиять. Вы что-то поломали. Создайте в вопросе воспроизводимый пример, используя кнопку "Фрагмент кода" или задайте новый вопрос.